# Diagnosing issues in PRU Timings?

Tags: assembly, embedded, led

TL:DR version of the question: my PRU sometimes lags its timings and throws off the devices downstream. How do I figure out *why*?

---

I'm using am AM335x CPU with two on-chip PRUs, to drive 32 strips of RGBW LEDs. A program running on the ARM CPU prepares the frame, and dumps it into PRU RAM. The PRU idles until the CPU sets a flag, at which point the PRU grabs the frame data 32 bytes at a time, and bitbangs them out.

Now, clearly, we're using the PRU because it can guarantee timings. I've gotta toggle high/low on timings which are the order of nanoseconds. And it works, at least *most* of the time. But there are points where the timing *lags*, and that throws off the data going down the wire and causes a flicker in the LEDs. It's *definitely* problems in timing- I've hooked up a logic analyzer and can spot situations where it spends 1083ns doing something it should have done in 600ns.

[Here's the core code](https://gist.github.com/RemyPorter/c9d047a3bd53cff4a7e48087a61472fa) in clpru assembly. There's an additional include file which just handles mapping GPIO pins to register addresses, and assigns a few registers aliases, it contains no logic.

The actual logic for banging out starts [here](https://gist.github.com/RemyPorter/c9d047a3bd53cff4a7e48087a61472fa#file-ledstrips-asm-L240), where we set a register to point at the start of the frame and then read the current cycle counter into a register. (I'm using a fair number of aliases and macros just to try and keep this readable).

We then grab 32-bytes [and stuff it into registers](https://gist.github.com/RemyPorter/c9d047a3bd53cff4a7e48087a61472fa#file-ledstrips-asm-L244) (scratch is register 11, so the 32-bytes spreads across r11-r18).

Then we take the first bit out of each byte and [align it with an output pin](https://gist.github.com/RemyPorter/c9d047a3bd53cff4a7e48087a61472fa#file-ledstrips-asm-L258). This is a big block of operations which takes up to 320ns to complete (two instructions in the macro, 32 executions of said macro).

Once everything is prepped [we wait](https://gist.github.com/RemyPorter/c9d047a3bd53cff4a7e48087a61472fa#file-ledstrips-asm-L297) until we're 550ns from the last `READ_TIME sleeper` call. `WAIT_NS` [reads the cycle counter](https://gist.github.com/RemyPorter/c9d047a3bd53cff4a7e48087a61472fa#file-ledstrips-asm-L92) in a busy loop.

The pattern for sending out for our LEDs is to send HIGH. For a zero, we hold approx 250ns (300ns is spec). For a one, we hold for approx 600ns. Then we hold until approx 1200ns have passed total.

We do this all relative to that `BASE_WAIT` of 550ns from before. At the end of the `BIT_LOOP` we [reset the sleeper](https://gist.github.com/RemyPorter/c9d047a3bd53cff4a7e48087a61472fa#file-ledstrips-asm-L320).

Again, 99% of the time (more!) this works fine. But once every few hundred frames, the timings get off. Something takes too long, and I can't understand *why*. And I definitely don't understand why it's fine almost all the time, and then jitters suddenly.

I have noticed that if a jitter happens, it almost certainly throws off the timing on fetching the next byte from PRU RAM. According to the docs, accessing PRU DRAM is deterministic. At the top and bottom of every frame, I do access DDR, just to check flags shared with the ARM program.

So my question is less "what's wrong" and more "how do I figure out what's wrong" or "what don't I understand about the PRU's realtime guarantees"?

I've tried hooking up prudebug, but I can't capture moments when it's glitching in there. I've got hundreds of megs of CSV files output from my logic analyzer, but all that's really told me is that every few hundred thousand bits, it glitches out for some reason. It sometimes remains stable for *millions* of bits. But then suddenly the PRU timing glitches out, but only ever by a few hundred nanoseconds. Enough to matter, but not so much as to make it obvious what's going wrong.

Comment: Based on other conversations, I suspect the root issue is that accessing the GPIO pins has to go through OCP, and that means the ARM CPU gets involved.

Comment: Does the PRU have its own GPIOs? Can you use those? Can the second PRU check the first (for debugging puposes)? Xout a changing value after each line in your program to the other PRU, which checks, whether the value has frozen.

Comment: The PRU has its own GPIOs, but not *enough*. The goal is to drive 32 channels.

Comment: The PRUs have an instruction counter, which can be activated. You can use one PRU for loading from memory and storing into GPIO and the other (with only non-memory operations) for keeping the timing. They both could communicate with xin/xout. You could not prevent the delay, but it would not traverse to later output.

Comment: If you have not solved it yet, you could also use an GPIO expander and use the PRU I/O with it.